# react native : there is way to display specific item from json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

there is way to display specific item from json ?
I want to get that every "COST_ELEMENT" that ending in 6000000 will be tomato and every "COST_ELEMENT" ending in 55 will be bob.
After displaying the data then I want to sum their "VALUE" and then display it within the total .

this is my json :

```
[
  {
    "ORDERID": "000005043283",
    "COST_ELEMENT": "0006000000",
    "ACTOR_ID": "APAZ",
    "VALUE": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "ORDERID": "000005043283",
    "COST_ELEMENT": "0041701055",
    "ACTOR_ID": "APAZ",
    "VALUE": "5000.00"
  }
]
```

this is my code as i trying to display the data but it doesnt work for me ,its gives undefined

```
 tableDataAccordion: [
            ['total'],
            ['tomato', this.props.headerInfo.costElement.filter(c => c.COST_ELEMENT.slice(-2) == 55)[0] && this.props.headerInfo.costElement.filter(c => c.COST_ELEMENT.slice(-2) == 55)[0].VALUE],
            ['bob', 'b'],
            ['sun', 'A'],
            ['person', 'b'],
            ['frog', 'F']
          ],
```